# What's the polarity of an ACER Aspire Notebook charger?

Tags: power-supply, acer-aspire

I can't find any information regarding the polarity of an ACER Aspire Notebook charger. I lost it, I have all kind of chargers but I need to know the polarity of the original charger.

I am familiar with the other requirements like volts and amps.

Comment: Acquiring a voltmeter or (digital) multimeter could be a worthwhile purchase.

Comment: [**Positive.**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7cjKw.png)

Comment: @sawdust It may be difficult to actually measure the polarity. With my charger, there's no way to actually insert any of the popular probe types deep enough to make contact with the inner conductor. Also for my 7720G, it's positive at the center and negative on the outside.

Comment: @Lucas Which notebook do you have exactly? Do you at least know the generation? Do you remember the manufacturer of the power supply? There's no way to answer this question in its current form except to list configuration for every type of power supply Acer ever shipped with its Aspire laptops.

Comment: @AndrejaKo - Difficult?!  If the center pin socket is that much smaller than a probe tip, then there's always a piece of solid wire or a resister lead.

Comment: @sawdust And sometimes even that may not make a good enough contact.

Comment: I take a small safety pin, unbend it so that it's straight, then cut off the tip. I can connect an alligator clip to the head and insert the thin pin into whatever hole (electronic of course `:-D`) that I need to. I have tested all kinds of hard-to-get-to circuits with it. Even better, I keep one yellow/goldish safety pin and one white/silverish one; that way it makes it easy to keep their polarities straight. The only downside is that they may introduce enough resistance to interfere, but not usually much without being completely covered in a patina (in which case I can just get another).

Answer (score 1):

Some information I have available:

Acer Aspire 4720z : positive at center, negative in the outside.
Acer Aspire One   : positive at center, negative in the outside.

Answer (score 1):

Like most electronics, it's **positive tip, negative barrel/ring**.

Back of an Acer Aspire Power Brick:
[image]